# IPTables rules and networking with problems 2

Tags: networking, routing, firewall, iptables, nat

My plan is to have a computer that forwards all traffic from internal interface `ens19` to openvpn-interface `tun0`. The system has 2 physical interfaces: `ens18` for local network with Internet connection via fritzbox & `ens19` for other network with OpenVPN via `tun0`.

I installed a host with Proxmox and 2 VMs, one with debian11 and one with ubuntu22 (2 VMs because the first setup didn't work, wanted to avoid problems by OS, both working as routers, both different IPs). Both VMs run the same setup: Installed minimal OS with current dependencies (without GUI).

So only setup that I installed (both VMs) is following:

```
apt install iptables openvpn

cat /etc/sysctl.conf | grep -v '#'

net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 1
```

iptables rules (experimental, via script)

```
#!/bin/bash

iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT

#iptables -A INPUT -i tun0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
#iptables -A INPUT -o ens19 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
#iptables -A INPUT -i tun0 -o ens19 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

#iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ens19 -j ACCEPT

#iptables -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i ens19 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o ens19 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i tun0 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -m state --state New,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
#iptables -A FORWARD -i ens19 -j ACCEPT

#iptables -t nat -s 192.168.1.0/24 -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
#iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE

iptables-save | sudo tee /etc/iptables/rules.v4

exit
```

(all executed)

```
sudo systemctl start openvpn@openvpn
```

Loads `/etc/openvpn/openvpn.conf` file from system

`iptables` results.

[image: iptables resulting]

Check with

```
ping web.de -I ens18    # (Network interface with route to "normal" router.) -> Working
ping web.de -I ens19    # (Network interface with firewall-rule forwarding to tun0.) -> Not working, but getting ip information of "web.de"
ping web.de -I tun0     # (Network interface by openvpn.) -> Working
```

My guess: NAT works, but not forwarding ens19 to tun0.

I found and read many many forums here and on other sites where people discuss the same idea and most of them found solutions (this is one "summary"-result of all). They just seem to not work for me. Strange :(

What am I missing so that traffic forwarding ens19 -> tun0 should be working? Any help would be great. Thanks

---

> Can you post the result of iptables-save ?

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Tue Jan  9 ...
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [40976:12561334]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [32894:54259570]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [32983:2879147]
-A INPUT -i tun0 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i ens19 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun0 -o ens19 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun0 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Jan  9 ...
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Tue Jan  9 ...
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [63033:10635529]
:INPUT ACCEPT [6276:710107]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1569:103282]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1156:77777]
-A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Jan  9 ...
```

> Also please post the results of these commands: ip route show and ip rule show

## `ip route show`

```
0.0.0.0/1 via ***.1 dev tun0
default via 192.168.178.254 dev ens18 proto static
***.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src ***
128.0.0.0/1 via <...>.1 dev tun0
*** via 192.168.178.254 dev ens18
192.168.1.0/24 dev ens19 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.1
192.168.178.0/24 dev ens18 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.178.6
```

- *** = very important ip address
- 192.168.178.0 = Network ens18 (= fritzbox)
- 192.168.1.0 = Network ens19 (= own network)
- 192.168.1.1 = Ip address of vpn router (the system itself)
- 192.168.1.254 = gateway (own network -> fritzbox network)

> Also please post the results of these commands: ip route show and ip rule show

## `ip rule show`

```
0:  from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

---

This is the result output of `sudo tcpdump -i ens19`. I hope this makes things more clear.
[image: ping web.de -I ens19]

This is the result output of `ping web.de -I ens19`
[image: ping web.de -I ens19]

Both cmds in own terminal, quick after each other, so tcpdump showed process of ping.

Comment: Can you post the result of `iptables-save` ?

Comment: Also please post the results of these commands: `ip route show` and `ip rule show`

Comment: Wow ... suddenly all inline-codings are in grouped blocks. Until yesterday all inline-coding was placed in own lines, kind of separated ... I'm surprised. Thanks to however did the magic xD

Comment: Thanks for answers @pepoluan. Text updates.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add some explanation or code instead of using the answer button as you did.

Comment: @help-info.de Done. Updated with some test-results.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, these should be set to 0:

```
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0
```

you really don't want the Linux router to be configurable by something outside of it.

Now on to your problem.

The problem with your setting is that, as configured, it cannot differ between packets being forwarded from `ens19` with packets that it generate on its own.

So first we need to create a new "routing table"; `ip route show` without a selector shows the `main` routing table ("main" is actually an alias of a numeric table, defined in `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`). Let's add to `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables` the following:

```
100 forwarding
```

Now, let's define how table `100`/`forwarding` behaves:

```
doas ip route add table forwarding to default dev tun0 via $NEXT_HOP
```

(Replace `doas` with `sudo` as needed.)

Next we need to 'mark' packets being forwarded, dump the current netfilter config to a file, and edit it to look like this:

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -i tun0 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i ens19 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun0 -o ens19 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i tun0 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Jan  9 ...
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Tue Jan  9 ...
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
### ADD THIS SECTION IF NOT EXIST ###
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -i ens19 -j MARK --set-mark 100
COMMIT
```

Commit the edited file using `doas iptables-apply -t 60 $FILENAME` (iptables-apply will auto-revert after several seconds [60 in this case] preventing you from inadvertently applying a rule that blocks you completely).

Verify you're still connected and you can open new connections.

Now finally we add a "policy routing" so that marked packets are sent to the `forwarding` table. Just for safety, let's put that command in a shellscript file, so it auto-removes the rule just in case:

```
#!/bin/bash
PRIO=1234
INITSLP=3
IPT_MARK=100
TABLE=forwarding

echo "#####"
echo "Sleeping $INITSLP seconds to allow time to start tail..."
sleep $INITSLP
echo "Adding rule..."
ip rule add prio $PRIO from all fwmark $IPT_MARK lookup $TABLE
echo "Rule added, please test. Waiting 120 seconds."
sleep 120
ip rule delete prio $PRIO
echo "Rule removed. Now you can stop tail using Ctrl-C"
echo "-----"
```

Execute the shellscript:

```
: > nohup.out ; doas nohup $SCRIPTNAME & tail -f nohup.out
```

If during the 120-second pause everything works:

- Packets get forwarded through `tun0`
- You're still connected to the Linux router
- New SSH connections can be made to the Linux router

Then let the sleep expire, and add the rule manually:

```
doas ip rule add prio 1234 from all fwmark 100 lookup forwarding
```

### In summary:

1. Make a new, separate routing table
2. Mark packets to be forwarded
3. Make a routing policy (rule)

Comment: Thx @pepoluan. Did all that, not sure how to check the new table, but ... no success :( Maybe following output after `ping web.de -I ens19` is helpful: getting `<timstamp> ARP, Reqeust who-has bap.web.de tell 192.168.1.1, length 28`.

Comment: I created a clone of that vm with same setup but only one interface = ens18 (and tun0) and told other system to use it as gateway. That works and tcpdump shows packets forwarding. So here the main difference might be the routing table as @pepoluan said.

Comment: Pls see updates with ping & tcpdump.

Comment: @kasper2083 hi sorry too tired last night to do testing. I'll check your updates.

Comment: May anyone else has ideas on this?